# Maximum product of any 3 numbers

Tags: c++

Given n numbers from o file calculate the maximum product that we can get with any three numbers.
Using of vectors or arrays is not accepted.
Numbers (int) from  file could be negative positive or even zeros.

What's the easiest method to solve this?
I was thinking about some possible cases: when all numbers are positive, negative, zeros but there are more like when there are positives and negatives together

Comment: What code have you written already, and what results are you seeing?  What is it doing wrong?

Comment: I don't understand the question. If you have a set of numbers and you want the maximum product, it will be achieved if you just take the three biggest numbers. And if you take any random combination of three numbers, the product will just be the result of multiplying them. I really don't get the question.

Comment: Not necessarily.  Two negative numbers and a positive number may produce a larger product than three positive numbers.  Consider { -100, -100, 10, 20, 100 }.

Comment: Ok, true. But having only 3 numbers, the only combination involving negative numbers is having EXACTLY 2 of them (which have to be the two "largest" negative numbers). So try multiplying the three biggest positive numbers AND try taking the two "biggest" negatives and the biggest positive, and the biggest of this two results is your answer.

Comment: You are using C++ but are forbidden to use array and vectors? What is wrong with this world?! On a more serious note, are you forbidden to use any STL container as well?

Comment: @Rerito This problem was given to one exam, since we are not allowed to use any easy way to solve we must discover some mathematical solution

Comment: @Paul the mathematical solution can be found in my answer

Answer (score 2):

I assume that the input set contains at least 4 integers (the solution is trivial if we have 3 integers...).

A few cases are of notable interest:

1. 2 or more negative integers, 1 or 2 positive integers
2. 2 or more negative integers, 3 or more positive integers
3. All positive integers
4. 1 negative integer, 3 or more positive integers
5. All negative integers

Let's think about the solution in each case. In the following discussion, `lowest` and `greatest` both refer to the common total order on integers: for instance, of -5 and -1, -1 is the greatest.

1. The desired output will be obtained by multiplying the 2 negative numbers with highest absolute value (ie. their mins) with the highest positive number. In other words the result is `lowest_negative*2nd_lowest_negative*greatest_positive`
2. Result is `max(3rd_greatest_positive*2nd_greatest_positive, lowest_negative*2nd_lowest_negative)*greatest_positive`
3. Result is `3rd_greatest_positive*2nd_greatest_positive*greatest_positive`
4. Same as 3.
5. Result is `3rd_greatest_negative*2nd_greatest_negative*greatest_negative`

From the cases above you can deduce a formula that solves the problem universally (which works for 3-elements sets as well as for any configuration of negative/positive integers):

> ```
> result = max(max1*min1*min2, max1*max2*max3)
> ```
>
> Where `max1` is the max of the input, `max2` the second greatest element, `max3` the third greatest element and `min1` and `min2` are the two lowest elements.

Now you could easily write a program to keep track of the 2 minimum elements and the 3 maximum elements (regardless of their sign!), then return `max(max1*min1*min2, max1*max2*max3)`

Here is a [C++ demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2e4f260ecd837d49) (using vector) just to demonstrate the accuracy of the formula. I leave you the I/O handling as an exercise.

Comment: what if all numbers are negative?

Comment: @tobi303 then you must take the product of the 3 maxes (ie. the negative integers with the lowest absolute value), the final formula shows it well.

Answer (score 1):

This is a rather mathematical question.

Without trying to proof my idea would be to take the numbers with the greatest absolute value and at the same time look for an even amount of negative numbers to produce a positive number.

Comment: I have a feeling it is going to be harder than this.  As [tobi](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4117728/tobi303) pointed out a set like -1 -1 -2 -2 -3 -3 -5 -5 should be a max of -2 which is hard to deal with.

Comment: True. Possibly you would need a special case for when there are only negative numbers available?

Answer (score 1):

There can be negative and positive numbers and it can also happen that all numbers are negative, thus you have to consider all possible cases:

The biggest product can be made of...

```
+++   all numbers positive  -> needs factors with large absolute value
++-   one negative          -> needs factors with small absolute value
+--   only one positive     -> needs factors with big ...
---   all negative          -> needs factors with small ...
```

As you cannot use arrays or vectors, you can do it like this:

For each above case, you need either all factors with maximum absolute value or minimum absolute value. You can go trough all given numbers and for each case store the three numbers that would make the biggest product for this case. In the end you just have to compare the 4 results and take the biggest one.

Answer (score 1):

> What's the easiest method to solve this?

Brute force.

Compute all products of 3 numbers in N choose 3 time, and then take the maximum.

How big is your input? You could reuse products of 2 numbers with a memoizing (dynamic programming) approach.

Comment: There are at least 3 numbers and maximum 10000

Answer (score 0):

find two largest numbers and two smallest numbers, and also a third largest number, if third number is positive return it and the pair that has the largest product, if it is negative return it and the pair that has the smallest product.

Comment: This does not consider negative numbers.

Comment: counter example:   -1  -1  -2 -2  -3 -3 -5 -5. Your algorithm will yield -50 while the biggest product is -2